# Advanced array sort PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a card game, and one page creates the game and inserts all the cards for each player into the MySQL database. c1,c2,c3... so on are stored by the random card that is chosen for you.

so, card1 will store in the database as an integer as c1 and so forth for the remaining 12 cards.

BUT

After the cards are returned on the game page from the databse, they go through an array to be organized with card pictures. Then they're displayed through two arrays for example.

```
            echo '<form input="index.php" method="post">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c1']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c1c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c2']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c2c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c3']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c3c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c4']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c4c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c5']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c5c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c6']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c6c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c7']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c7c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c8']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c8c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c9']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c9c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c10']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c10c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c11']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c11c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c12']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c12c">';
            echo $cards[$fetch['c13']].'<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="c13c">';
            print_r($fetch);
```

`$cards` being the picture sorter.

`$fetch` being the returned array from the database.

```
            $query = "SELECT c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13 FROM games WHERE comp = 0";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

            $fetch = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            asort($fetch);
```

Now this code provides me with exactly what I need, the `print_r` returns

`Array ( [c9] => 3 [c5] => 6 [c10] => 8 [c11] => 13 [c13] => 15 [c3] => 16 [c2] => 18 [c1] => 19 [c4] => 24 [c8] => 40 [c12] => 44 [c7] => 45 [c6] => 47 )`
Organized ascending, BUT when then I display the cards, I cannot figure out how to make them run in that order, as the key is the column name from the database, and the value I cannot ask for in the display.

So my basic question is, how do I sort the cards so that they run through my current array for sorting pictures to the cards ascending?

If required;

```
            $cards = array(
                    "0" => "<img src=\"cards/dead.png\"/>",
                    "1" => "<img src=\"cards/2_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "2" => "<img src=\"cards/3_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "3" => "<img src=\"cards/4_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "4" => "<img src=\"cards/5_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "5" => "<img src=\"cards/6_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "6" => "<img src=\"cards/7_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "7" => "<img src=\"cards/8_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "8" => "<img src=\"cards/9_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "9" => "<img src=\"cards/10_of_spades.png\"/>",
                    "10" => "<img src=\"cards/jack_of_spades2.png\"/>",
                    "11" => "<img src=\"cards/queen_of_spades2.png\"/>",
                    "12" => "<img src=\"cards/king_of_spades2.png\"/>",
                    "13" => "<img src=\"cards/ace_of_spades.png\"/>",

                    "14" => "<img src=\"cards/2_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "15" => "<img src=\"cards/3_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "16" => "<img src=\"cards/4_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "17" => "<img src=\"cards/5_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "18" => "<img src=\"cards/6_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "19" => "<img src=\"cards/7_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "20" => "<img src=\"cards/8_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "21" => "<img src=\"cards/9_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "22" => "<img src=\"cards/10_of_clubs.png\"/>",
                    "23" => "<img src=\"cards/jack_of_clubs2.png\"/>",
                    "24" => "<img src=\"cards/queen_of_clubs2.png\"/>",
                    "25" => "<img src=\"cards/king_of_clubs2.png\"/>",
                    "26" => "<img src=\"cards/ace_of_clubs.png\"/>",

                    "27" => "<img src=\"cards/2_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "28" => "<img src=\"cards/3_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "29" => "<img src=\"cards/4_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "30" => "<img src=\"cards/5_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "31" => "<img src=\"cards/6_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "32" => "<img src=\"cards/7_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "33" => "<img src=\"cards/8_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "34" => "<img src=\"cards/9_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "35" => "<img src=\"cards/10_of_hearts.png\"/>",
                    "36" => "<img src=\"cards/jack_of_hearts2.png\"/>",
                    "37" => "<img src=\"cards/queen_of_hearts2.png\"/>",
                    "38" => "<img src=\"cards/king_of_hearts2.png\"/>",
                    "39" => "<img src=\"cards/ace_of_hearts.png\"/>",

                    "40" => "<img src=\"cards/2_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "41" => "<img src=\"cards/3_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "42" => "<img src=\"cards/4_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "43" => "<img src=\"cards/5_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "44" => "<img src=\"cards/6_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "45" => "<img src=\"cards/7_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "46" => "<img src=\"cards/8_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "47" => "<img src=\"cards/9_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "48" => "<img src=\"cards/10_of_diamonds.png\"/>",
                    "49" => "<img src=\"cards/jack_of_diamonds2.png\"/>",
                    "50" => "<img src=\"cards/queen_of_diamonds2.png\"/>",
                    "51" => "<img src=\"cards/king_of_diamonds2.png\"/>",
                    "52" => "<img src=\"cards/ace_of_diamonds.png\"/>"
            );
```

Comment: You know you can actually use print_r if you like - you can return it back to your code, rather than the output buffer, with something like `$aPrintedData = print_r($aVariable, true);`

Comment: Doesn't a `foreach($fetch as $card){}` return them in order?

Comment: Would that help me? I'm assuming it would just create an identical array to the `$fetch` I already have..? Also, the print_r I have in the code was purely for debugging.

Comment: ... maybe - I thought I'd just post that as an interesting aside whilst I'm puzzling through the question ... I'm still trying to figure out exactly what you're sorting on. You've used `asort($fetch)` so the array **should** already be sorted by value... `ksort($fetch)` would sort it by key.

Comment: I'm trying to sort the values returned from the database, into an ascending order. (So that the cards will be displayed neatly rather than.. Well.. Randomly).

Comment: But asort, does order them. It's calling them in my echos so that it returns the correct order of the sorted cards. As calling `c1` `c2` just returns to order from the database.

Comment: Are you trying to re-order `$cards` to match the order of `$fetch` ? The fetch array is already in the "right" order after the `asort()` .. so as @Cyntech said, if you loop through it, that will be the order in which the data is read... is it just a simple matter of `foreach($fetch as $cardId) { echo $cards[$cardId]; }`

Comment: That's exactly it, I will run through it and let you know.

Comment: Works a charm, if you answer the question I'll approve it.

Comment: hehe - @Cyntech should really answer it - it was his solution, I just mapped it to your data ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I go about keeping a unique `name="c'.$key.'c">';` for the form with a foreach?

Comment: you can maintain the key in a foreach loop with something to the effect of `foreach($fetch as $key => $value)` $key will then hold your 'c' value (the database field name) whilst $value holds the "card id"

Comment: I'll answer it in a tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `foreach` ([doco here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)) should return them in the right order.

```
foreach($fetch as $cardId => $card) {
    echo 'CardID: ' . $cardId . '<br>';
    echo 'Card: ' . $cards[$card] . '<br>';
}
```

Where `$cardId` is the key (e.g. 'c1') and `$card` is the card's ID value (e.g. 3).

[PHPFiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/dc3-dbp)